# Access VBA - close Excel object

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have some code for exporting subform results to Excel workbook. Code works fine, only one small issue. If I do export, excel file opens If user wants I open. When this Excel file is opened and user wants to do Export again, I receive error 1004.

This error is produced because file is open, and new Excel object want to save a file with same name. What I want is when this happens, just cancel everything and let user know that he must first close this previously created workbook. Here is what I tried:

```
If Err.Number = 1004 Then

MsgBox "Error. You have opened Excel file, that has same name as this file name should be. Please close that file first !", vbCritical

 Cancel = True

 Set wb = Nothing ' wb is wb=XcelFile.Workbooks.Add

 Set XcelFile = Nothing ' Xcelfile is Xcelfile= New Excel.Application

End If
```

This code works, when user closes that file, export can be performed - old file is just overwritted. Problem is that Excel application is still opened in Windows Task Manager, so Excel object is not properly closed.

Does anybody have a better solution ?

P.S.: I tried including numbers in file name of Excel, so that It wouldn't be same name, but I can't get It fixed.

EDIT: Here is how I tried changing filename

```
   Dim i as Integer

       ExcelFilename = "RESULTS_" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "_" & i & "_" & ".xlsx"

 i = i + 1
```

"i" doesn't change It's value when I run code once again. How can I make it increment ? This would solve my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a simple solution: add the time to the file name to prevent conflicts.

```
ExcelFilename = "RESULTS_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd_hh-nn-ss") & ".xlsx"
```

For a number that will increment as long as the application is running, try

```
Static i As Integer
```

[Static variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have tested this too, but I would prefer a number increment, like RESULTS_16_04_2016-1,RESULTS_16_04_2016-2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must be very strict in opening the Excel objects and closing them in *reverse* order - as done in this example:

```
Public Sub RenameWorkSheet()

    Dim xls     As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb     As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks     As Excel.Worksheet

    Set xls = New Excel.Application
    Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open("c:\test\workbook1.xlsx")
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)

    wks.Name = "My New Name"
    wkb.Close True

    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing

    xls.Quit

    Set xls = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: No, this unfortunally doesn't work while Excel file with same name is open. I think only solution is to change filename dynamically. But I can't achive this, take a look at my edit, you'll see how I tried this.

Comment: Of course, if Excel already has opened the file, you cannot open it again.

Comment: Yes, but when renaming file, code works. So I just have to increment some number in filename. But I can't get a proper code for this, somekind of Loop has to be performed.